# How to recursively remap array in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion

How to recursively remap children to nodes? I tried writing recursive function, but it only runs one iteration. Array map - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php would only run for single dimension

I'm using nested sets model https://github.com/etrepat/baum#getting-started Input is generated by dumping all hierarchy

```
$array = Category::where('name', '=', 'All')->first()->getDescendantsAndSelf()->toHierarchy()->toArray();

/* Input */
$array = array(
'category_id' => 0,
'children' => array(
    array(
        'category_id' => 1,
        'children' => array(
            'category_id' => 2,
            'children' => array(
                'category_id' => 3,
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => 4,
        'children' => array(
            'category_id' => 5,
            'children' => array(
                'category_id' => 6,
            )
        )
    )
)
);
```

Output should be

```
/*
$array = array(
'category_id' => 0,
'nodes' => array(
    array(
        'category_id' => 1,
        'nodes' => array(
            'category_id' => 2,
            'nodes' => array(
                'category_id' => 3,
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => 4,
        'nodes' => array(
            'category_id' => 5,
            'nodes' => array(
                'category_id' => 6,
            )
        )
    )
)
);*/


function remap($items){
    if(!empty($items['children'])){
        $items['nodes'] = $items['children'];
        unset($items['children']);
        return remap($items['nodes']);
    }
    else{
        return $items;

    }
}
print_r(remap($array));
```

Comment: Why is it important to change the `children` key to `nodes`?

Comment: I have to remap eloquent collection to output json for treeview plugin. https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview plugin requires data to be in specified format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit complicated couse , `childrens` content variates by depth

```
function remap(array &$items){
    if(array_key_exists('children',$items)){
        $items['nodes'] = $items['children'];
        unset($items['children']);
        if(array_key_exists('children',$items['nodes'])){
            $items['nodes']['nodes'] = $items['nodes']['children'];
            unset($items['nodes']['children']);
        }
        foreach ($items['nodes'] as  &$x) {
            if (is_array($x)) {
                remap($x);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        return $items;

    }
}
remap($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: thank you, this solution works. Maybe you know a solution specific to nested sets? https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you ask

Comment: maybe there is a way to extend Baum\Node to get the same result

Comment: I see but that's too much code and i've got so little time

Answer (score 0):

This function will change the `children` keys to `nodes`.

```
function remap($items) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'children') {
            $result['nodes'] = remap($value);
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$new_array = remap($array);
```

After your comment, though, it seems like it would be easier to create an accessor that maps `children` to `nodes` in your Eloquent model and use that in the select that gets your collection.